# Deploying Grails 3 to Wildfly 10 - getting 404

Tags: grails, wildfly-10

This is my second app being published to wildfly 10 as standalone and first one which uses grails 3 with angular front end; which is restful.

I can hit the main page as follows:
https://fin-test01.aus.edu:8443/fytrnlt/#/

but any calls to api's are returning 404. Example
https://fin-test01.aus.edu:8443/fytrnlt/#/api/fytrnlt

My UrlMappings.groovy has all api calls set as follows "/api/fytrnlt/getUserName"(controller: 'fybkbra', action: 'getUserid')

From development server, which works fine, the respective calls are:
http://localhost:8080/#/
http://localhost:8080/#/api/fytrnlt

I published the application as war file named 'fytrnlt' . Is there some config changes I have to make in wildfly to call my api mappings?

Thanks,

Comment: See http://grails.io/post/142674392718/deploying-grails-3-to-wildfly-10

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found that article which solved some of my other issues but not the 404 problem.